# Angular connection settings in Azure

Tags: angularjs, azure

What's the best practice for storing connection strings and the like for AngularJs so that they can be changed in production environments?

E.g. my angular web app points to a REST APIlike so:

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", ['ngRoute']);

app.apiUrls = {
    base: "http://localhost:1120/api/"
};
```

How can I specify a different URL for my REST API in a production environment, specifically Azure?

Answer (score 0):

I just put the connection string into a AngularJS service file, something like

```
app.shared.services.value('apiAddress', 'http://10.222.115.220:8080/api');
```

When deploying I didn't upload this file so that it will be keep the value for Azure.